# How To Use Go local package In terminal

Tags: go, package

How can I link my local cmd go package on my computer? In npm we use npm link on the root of the package and a symlink will be created for the package to be used on the terminal how to do that with Go?

Comment: Just add `$GOPATH/bin` to your `PATH`. `go install` places binaries in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: Or just use `go build` and put the binary wherever you want, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`. Unlike Node programs, a Go program is a single file you can easily put wherever you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in macOS, your package is `app`, put your `app` folder in `go/src/app` `cd` in your `app` folder and type `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` enter, and `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` enter, then run your package. just type `app` and enter